# Building strings in ASP.NET MVC Helpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, helper

What is the best approach when building strings in html Helpers? Are Stringbuilders good enough when attached to MvcHtmlString.Create(stringbuilder)? Is there another approach which is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StringBuilder` is fine but you could also use `System.Web.Mvc.TagBuilder` when building HTML content in your helper.